# How to assemble a list of options?

Tags: vb.net, function

I will take an example of the method DialogResult.

When we write DialogResult. A list of options appears: Ok, Cancel, Yes, No, so on.

I wonder how to do this.

I'm doing a method that requires two variables, and more or less like the code below:

```
Public Function funcao_teste(ByVal var_one As String, ByVal var_two As String)
    ...
End Function
```

Well, the "var_two" only has 3 possible answers, so I'd like to replace it for a type that has the trees possible answers I want, like the example below:

```
AlgumaCoisa.OPTION_ONE
AlgumaCoisa.OPTION_TWO
AlgumaCoisa.OPTION_THREE
```

So when I was calling the function would look like this:

```
funcao_teste("Value of var_one", AlgumaCoisa.OPTION_ONE);
```

Is how to do this?

Comment: Does my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043093/how-to-assemble-a-list-of-options/19043131#19043131) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Enumerator.

```
Private Enum AlgumaCoisa
    OPTION_ONE
    OPTION_TWO
    OPTION_THREE
End Enum
```

Then as parameter in your method, use

```
Public Function funcao_teste(ByVal var_one As String, ByVal var_two As AlgumaCoisa)
```

On calling your method, intellisense will provide you the options available.

Answer (score 0):

Create an enumerator out of your options and then in your function use this instead of string.

```
Enum YourEnumerator
OPTION_ONE = 1
OPTION_TWO = 2
OPTION_THREE = 3
End Enum

Public Function funcao_teste(ByVal var_one As String, ByVal var_two As YourEnumerator)
    ...
End Function
```